# javascript code for finding maximum value from an array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get a print out statement from this code i wrote but i dont know why it is not printing anything.

```
    var max = 0;
    var i;
    var array=new array [5];

    i=prompt("Enter 5 numbers to find the max");
    i=parseFloat(i);

    for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    if (array[i]>max)
    max=array[i];}

    alert("your highest number is " + max );        
    document.write("max = " + max);
```

Comment: Where you fill an array that create ?

Comment: `var array=new array [5];` is not valid Javascript. You really need to learn your browser's Javascript console to diagnose these errors yourself.

Comment: it should be `array = new Array(5);`, also your code does not input any number into the array.

Comment: alert("Hi Num: "+Math.max.apply(0,Array.apply(0, Array(5)).map(prompt.bind(top, "Enter Number"))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this out

```
var max = 0;
var i;
var array=[];
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
var number=prompt("Enter 5 numbers to find the max");
number=parseFloat(number);
if(number>max)
 max=number;
 // if you need to hold the value
 array.push(number);
}


alert("your highest number is " + max );        
document.write("max = " + max);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your array is never receiving the values.  They are going to the i variable.  Also, the prompt isn't going to store the entered data as an array.  You'd have to loop it.

```
var array=new array [5];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
     array.push(prompt("Enter 5 numbers to find the max"));

array.sort();

alert("your highest number is " + array[0] );        
document.write("max = " + array[0]);
```

I have no idea if this works, but it's close to what you want to be aiming for.

Comment: can you show me with the code on how to fix it. this is my first day trying javascript. thankyou

Comment: This will not work. You almost have it, but you can't use sort like that.

Comment: @shivaupadhyay: If you're brand new to JavaScript I'd recommend a taking a few quick courses on [Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com) and [this beginners' tutorial](https://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/tutorials/Programming_-_the_real_basics). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution with explanation in action
http://jsfiddle.net/dr7g5qLg/

Understand that this is the OPs first attempt, but as a lot of posters have said, try read a lot more Javascript examples and books. Array handling and manipulation is a fundamental of programming and the main issue here is a lack of understanding by the OP on how to populate the array in Javascript.

```
var max = 5;
var i;
var array=new Array();

// Populate your array
for(i=1; i <= max; i++){
    array[i]=prompt("Enter "+i+" of "+max+" numbers to find the max");
}

// Sort the array in descending order
// basically pass in an anonymous function to determine sort order
array.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});

// After sorting, the first element of the array contains your max value
var determined_max = array[0];

alert("your highest number is " + determined_max );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it without using array also as below:

```
<script>
    var max = 0;
    var inputVal;

    for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
         inputVal=prompt("Enter "+(i+1)+" of 5 numbers to find the max");
           if (inputVal>max)
                 max=inputVal;
    }

    alert("your highest number is " + max );        
    document.write("max = " + max);

</script>
```